RDLC Report - Text alignment is ignored on rendered report
We are currently moving from Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2018 to Business Central. While doing so, we are re-designing our RDLC Reports and I am running into a extremely frustrating issue:
I have built our company header in the Report like this:
RDLC Report Company Header
As you can see, the textboxes have right aligned text. My issue occurs once I am executing the report in Business Central, which now looks as follows:
RDLC Report rendered output
I have tried lots of different things I have found around the internet, but was not able to successfully solve this issue after hours.

Converting the field values to String
Adding filler characters
Hardcoded values
Multiple different expressions

After adding a background color to the textboxes, I can see that the textbox has the correct size and doesn't shrink or grow:
RDLC Report colorized textboxes
But the issue seems to persist, no matter what I try.
It seems like the fields go through a post processing step that I can't check upon. That's just a wild guess, but it only happens to fields that resemble specific formats as dates, mail addresses, websites, telephone numbers...

The issue was caused by installing Arial Font from my Windows to the Windows Docker Container that runs my development environment.
The issue is gone after deleting every font that was not native to my docker container.
Sucks that I can't use anything but monospace for designing reports, but it is what it is...
